# php validation form does not send email

Tags: php, html, forms, validation

I am trying to make an HTML form work.

My frontend code is this:

```
<form action="/form_validation.php" target="_blank">
    <p><input class="w3-input w3-padding-16" type="text" placeholder="name" required name="name"></p>
    <p><input class="w3-input w3-padding-16" type="text" placeholder="email" required name="email"></p>
    <p><input class="w3-input w3-padding-16" type="text" placeholder="subject" required name="subject"></p>
    <p><input class="w3-input w3-padding-16" type="text" placeholder="comment" required name="comment"></p>
    <p>
        <button class="w3-button w3-light-grey w3-padding-large" type="submit">
            <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> SEND MESSAGE
        </button>
    </p>
</form>
<p><?php echo $feedbackmsg;?></p>
```

and the file `form_validation.php` contains this:

```
<?php

$nameErr = $emailErr = $commentErr = $subjectErr = "";
$name = $email = $comment = $subject = "";
$feedbackmsg = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
            $nameErr = "*Name is required";
        } else {
            $name = validate($_POST["name"]);
            if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $name)) {
                $nameErr = "*Only letters and white space allowed";
            }
        }

        if (empty($_POST["subject"])) {
            $subjectErr = "*Subject is required";
        } else {
            $subject = validate($_POST["subject"]);
            if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $subject)) {
                $SubjectErr = "*Only letters and white space allowed";
            }
        }

        if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
            $emailErr = "*Email is required";
        } else {
            $email = validate($_POST["email"]);
            if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email)) {
                $emailErr = "*Invalid email format";
            }
        }

        if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
            $commentErr = "*Write Me something";
        } else {
            $comment = validate($_POST["comment"]);
        }

        if (empty($nameErr) && empty($emailErr) && empty($commentErr)) {
            $to = "myEmail@gmail.com";
            $subject = $name;
            mail($to, $subject, $comment, $email);
            $feedbackmsg = "Your message has sent,<br> thanks";
        }
    }
}
```

So when action triggered returns back a blank page with the following url with my summury:
mysite.com/form_validation.php?name=anastasios&email=myemail%40hotmail.com&subject=mysubject&comment=ena+dio+ena+dio

I think this shoyld be normal. but why I dont have any email if it works properly?
Any thoughts? thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

All of your logic is wrapped in this condition:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
```

And this condition (as well as subsequent conditions therein, if the code got to them) is `false` because you're using `GET` instead of `POST`.  Specify the `POST` method in your form:

```
<form action="/form_validation.php" target="_blank" method="post">
```

Comment: oh yes right, but even that way I get new blank page with url mysite.com/form_validation.php and still does not get any mail.
instead of action="form_validation" I tried action="<?php mail()?>" and works to get email but without the summury. Of course I dont like to get emails in that way, without validation, but it was just to try an other way to be sure that my form works.

Comment: @fxp869: Do some debugging.  The page is blank because you never output anything.  (Or because there's an error and you don't have error reporting turned on.)  Check the PHP logs, add some kind of output to test the logic, etc.  Your code is not a black box that either completely works or completely doesn't work.  You can debug it.  (And no, `action="<?php mail()?>"` won't do anything remotely like what you might expect it to do.  Just randomly moving code around is not debugging.)